# DHCP Search ip address/hostname

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, dhcp-server

In the context of a Service Desk, the engineers have to lookup the IP addresses in the DHCP server a lot. For example to use a VNC viewer.

I can't find a tool on the internet that actually makes it possible to search for an ip address, hostname or mac address in the leased addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following PowerShell cmdlet:

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease
```

example:

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId 192.168.1.0 |Where-Object {$_.IPAddress -eq "192.168.1.100"}
```

What I would do is schedule the creation of a CSV file regularly so the Service Desk team can easily search in it:

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId 192.168.1.0 |Export-Csv -Path \\myFileServer\DHCPInfo\dhcp.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you, this might be a very viable option.
I'll try to implement it has quickly as possible and post the results here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with DHCP (and assuming this is on a domain), just make sure your DHCP Scopes are set to register DNS. You can either set it to update per the client's request (which means the DNS setting needs to be enabled on their adapter), or have the DNS server update itself when there is a new lease given (this removes the need to have it specified on the client machine). Also, you can have it discard records after the lease is deleted, to keep the DNS zone clean.

[image: DHCP dynamic DNS]

This way, your Service Desk can just use the hostname in VNC viewer, or simply ping its FQDN to get the IP.